# Multisite Wordpress Configurtion

Tags: multisite, redirect, subdomains

We have a production wordpress server which has a single site up and running. Assume site name is `www.example.com`

How we want to host multiple subdomains in the same machine. I enabled multisite with current site name `www.example.com`. Now problem is, i could not create new site under my qualified domain name example.com. Its automatically taking `www.example.com` as my qualified domain name and allowing me to create subdomain under this..

What is the way to create a site with domain `beta.example.com` while my current site `www.example.com` up and running?
[small downtime is not an issue]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: apache or nginx?

Comment: @FedericoGalli Its wordpress running on apache

Comment: 1) dns record, `*.example.com IN CNAME www.example.com`
2) apache vhost config add `ServerAlias *.example.com`